# Create helm source containing multi-term buffers

Tags: helm, multi-term, helm-sources

I am using multi-term and would like to create a helm source which displays all my open terminals. There is a list of all terminal buffers called "multi-term-buffer-list", but I can't get this list into the candidates for the helm source. I tried several combinations along these lines:

```
(setq some-helm-source
  '((name . "Terminal Buffers")
    (candidates . multi-term-buffer-list)))

(helm :sources '(some-helm-source))
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try `(helm :sources 'some-helm-source)`. Have you seen the [wiki](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Developing)?

Comment: The result is the same. It opens the helm buffer, but there are no candidates to choose from. The problem seems to be getting the candidates from the multi-term-buffer-list into the helm source.

Comment: I think the problem is that Helm sources need to be a list of strings, while `multi-term-buffer-list` is a list of buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check out the [wiki on developing for Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Developing). If you find anything unclear, be sure to create an issue and explain it clearly so others can benefit!

I don't use `multi-term`, but it seems that the problem is that `multi-term-buffer-list` returns a list of buffers. Helm needs a list of strings to display.

What you need is a list of candidates of the form `(display . candidate)`, where `display` is a string to display and `candidate` is the actual object (in this case, a process) to take actions on.

Here is a minimal example:

```el
(helm :sources
      (helm-build-sync-source "Multi-term buffers"
        :candidates (mapcar (lambda (buffer)
                              (cons (buffer-name buffer) buffer))
                            multi-term-buffer-list)
        :action '(("Switch to buffer" . switch-to-buffer))))
```

Comment: multi-term-buffer-list is a variable not a function

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I ended up using a slightly different solution. Doing it like it was shown in the answer in [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13440/decomposing-helm-source-buffers-list-in-two-parts) I get a terminal list with additional information about the terminals.

```
(defclass my-helm-source-terminal-buffers-class (helm-source-buffers)
   ((candidates :initform
               (lambda ()
                 (mapcar 'buffer-name multi-term-buffer-list)))))

(setq my-helm-source-terminal-buffers-list
      (helm-make-source "Terminals" 'my-helm-source-terminal-buffers-class))

(defun my-helm-terminal-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources 'my-helm-source-terminal-buffers-list
        :buffer "*helm terminals*"))
```

I really need to learn emacs lisp, at the moment I have no clue what I am really doing...

Comment: I'd start with [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html), which I recommend you read from beginning to end (and do the exercises!). Then, proceed to the [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html), which I do *not* recommend you try to read from cover to cover; instead, do a deep-dive into the functionality that interests you.

Comment: For Helm in particular, take a look at the aforementioned Wiki, as well as other resources like Tuhdo's (very extensive!) [Helm tutorial](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html).